# Exoplayer plays new Playlist from the beginning instead of provided position

Tags: android, exoplayer

I Implemented DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource in my project and have reached a bug where in the method `exoPlayer.prepare(source);` the songs starts  to play at the beginning of the playlist before `exoPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition, C.TIME_UNSET);` is callled. 
So this causes a UI bug on my app.

For an already cached song, a user can hear the first song playing before moving to the next song.

#### I Play a song from here and compare if its a new list, i reinitialise exoplayer.

```
  private BroadcastReceiver playNewAudio = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            try {
                if (!exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady()) {
                    resumeMedia();
                    sendBroadcast(Dispatcher.Broadcast.NEW_TRACK_PLAYING, "");
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Get the new media index form SharedPreferences
        if (songManager.currentPosition != -1 && songManager.currentPosition < songManager.getCurrentPlayList().size()) {
            //index is in a valid range
            songManager.activeTrack = songManager.getCurrentPlayList().get(songManager.currentPosition);
            //sendBroadcast(Dispatcher.Broadcast.NEW_TRACK_PLAYING,"");
            if (songManager.getPreviousPlaylist().equals(songManager.currentPlayList))

                seekToCurrent(songManager.currentPosition);

            else
                initExo();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }

        /*stopMedia();*/
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            try {
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            initExo();
        }
        /*initMediaPlayer();*/
        updateMetaData();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);

    }
};
```

#### Here is where i initialise Exo

```
  private void initExo() {
    songManager = SongManager.getInstance();
    int currentPosition = songManager.getCurrentPosition();
    window = new Timeline.Window();
    defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

    trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(defaultBandwidthMeter);

    trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);

    boolean newExo = exoPlayer == null;

    if (newExo)
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);

    exoPlayer.addListener(this);
    source = initMediaSource();
    exoPlayer.prepare(source);
    exoPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition, C.TIME_UNSET);
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);


}
```

#### Then the call to initMediaSource

```
    private DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource initMediaSource() {
    clearSource();
    DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource mediaSource = new DynamicConcatenatingMediaSource();
    for (Track track : songManager.getCurrentPlayList()) {
        if (track != null && !track.getSource().isEmpty()) {
            HlsMediaSource source = new
                    HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(track.getSource()), cacheDataSourceFactory(), 5,   null, null);
            mediaSource.addMediaSource(source);
        } else {
            Log.e("Bad_Track", track.toString());
        }
    }
    songManager.setPreviousPlaylist(songManager.currentPlayList);
    return mediaSource;
}
```

This works fine in the same Playlist. 
I was able to find this issue as i added Breakpoints on that line and notices the music started playing as soon as i left the `onPrepared` method.